# How to assign values in a range of elements inside a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector of ints, like `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. I need to increase `v[i]` by 1 for a range of elements, like `v[1]` to `v[3]` so that I have `{0, 1, 1, 1, 0}`. How to do that?

Comment: std::span in c++20

Comment: You can use `transform` or `fill`, depending on your needs. You can also use iterators to get a subrange of your vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple iterative loop, eg:

```
std::vector<int> v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
for(size_t i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    v[i]++;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/qrYJpI)

Which you can also replicate using standard library algorithms like `std::for_each()` and `std::transform()`, eg:

```
std::vector<int> v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
std::for_each(v.begin()+1, v.begin()+4,
    [](int& i){ ++i; }
);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/oDkETp)

```
std::vector<int> v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
std::transform(v.begin()+1, v.begin()+4, v.begin()+1,
    [](int i){ return i+1; }
);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Dro2Xk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::fill`.

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int i = 1, j = 3;  // [start, end]

std::fill(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + j + 1, 1);
```

If you are using C++20 or later and are feeling adventurous, you can store this slice as a view and then fill it.

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int i = 1, j = 3;  // [start, end]
auto vSlice = ans | std::views::drop(i) | std::views::take(j - i + 1);

std::ranges::fill(vSlice, 1);

// The below line also works
std::fill(vSlice.begin(), vSlice.end(), 1);
```